splitting a hyper parameter grid to n-equal size subgrids
imagine you have a number of lists in python that build a large hyperparameter grid:
hp= {
   "p1": [1,2,3,4 ...],
   "p2": ['a', 'b' , ... ],
   ...
   }

how can you splits this hyper parameter grid to n subgrids such that:
1- the total combinations in the this n  subgrids cover the total possibke combinations in the original large grid
and
2- all subgrids have roughly the same number of elements in them?
size(n1)~size(n2)~ ...
is there any algorithm for this?
